# Singularity $z/\sin(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

I'm trying to figure out the singularity of $$\frac z {\sin(z)}$$
I understand how it works with $$\frac {\sin(z)} z$$

But here I don't know what to do. I know, that the solution is that it has a pole of order $1$ and as well a removable singularity at zero.

Comment: the function $f(z):=\frac{z}{\sin(z)}$ have a singularity each time $\sin(z)=0$. It doesn't happen just when $z=0$

Answer (score 1):

That function has a removable singularity at $0$ (and no pole there), since$$\lim_{z\to0}\frac z{\sin z}=1.$$